# What is the misstake in this code in python+pandas

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I learing panda as I am working with large datasets. So far has been fine in the learning process. However, at moment I am confused with adding a new columns, as my current code adds a new row intead, despite following some guides.

I have google and tried different approuches.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('L178.csv', delimiter = ';')
print df.dtypes
output:
Time Stamp                                        object
/x1 /50KV    /L178    /-P*     /MvMoment    float64
/x2 /50KV    /L178    /-Q*     /MvMoment    float64
/x3 /50KV    /L178    /-U*     /MvMoment    float64
/x4/50KV    /L178    /-P*     /MvMoment    float64
/x5/50KV    /L178    /-Q*     /MvMoment    float64
/x6/50KV    /L178    /-U*     /MvMoment    float64
dtype: object

#make new data frame, with only Time stamp by copying Time stamp from df and add a new value with constant value zero.

df3 = df["Time Stamp"].copy()
df3['new'] = 0

''''

As you see the new column ends as row, and I don't fully understand why it does so. 
The expected result:
'''python
output:                         new
0        2019-02-14 10:00:00    0
1        2019-02-14 10:05:00    0
2        2019-02-14 10:10:00    0
3        2019-02-14 10:15:00    0
4        2019-02-14 10:20:00    0
5        2019-02-14 10:25:00    0
6        2019-02-14 10:30:00    0

The actual ouput
0        2019-02-14 10:00:00
1        2019-02-14 10:05:00
2        2019-02-14 10:10:00
3        2019-02-14 10:15:00
4        2019-02-14 10:20:00
5        2019-02-14 10:25:00
6        2019-02-14 10:30:00
new           0
''''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df3 = df["Time Stamp"].copy()` is copying a pandas Series, not dataframe. to make it copy a dataframe, change it to:
`df3 = df[["Time Stamp"]].copy()`